# gnuplot in windows requires to close and re-open to replot after an error of "You can not change the terminal ..."

Tags: gnuplot

I have problem with "You can't change the terminal in multiplot mode" although instructions from stackoverflow have been followed; for example, in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388994/how-to-output-a-file-in-gnuplot-multiplot-mode). The error appears again and again unless I close gnuplot and reopen it (change directory in gnuplot windows is time-consuming). Does anyone know how to recall the gnuplot commander without close and re-open again and again?
[Error in gnuplor that requires the command window to be closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX33f.png)
File `input0.gnu`:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced
set colorsequence classic
```

File `input1.gnu` (I was recommended to separate the files)

```
set output 'mode_10_hikui.eps'
```

File `run.gnu`:

```
set size 1.01,0.86
set multiplot

set size 1,0.6
set origin 0,0
set lmargin 6
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [-0.1:0.2]

set xlabel "r" offset 0,1
set ylabel "dz_L/dr" offset 2,0

unset border
set border 4095 lw 0.3
plot exp(x) w l lw 3 dashtype 3

reset
set size 1,0.4
set origin 0,0.5
set lmargin 6
set format y ""
set logscale y
set yrange [0.2:14]

unset xtics
set border 4095 lw 0.3
plot exp(x) w l lw 3 dashtype 3

set nomultiplot
unset multiplot
unset output
pause 2
reread
```

Comment: Please show your exact script. As the message says, you are still in multiplot mode, so you are probably missing an `unset multiplot`.

Comment: I did add the `unset multiplot`.

Comment: As also stated in the answer to the question you linked: Iterating with `reread` is an infinite loop which you probably terminate with Ctrl+C. This causes the script to be terminated wherever it currently is, and probably skipping the necessary `unset multiplot`. I'll see if I can give you a solution with a graceful termination.

Comment: Actually, `reread` was added in an effort to overcome the above problem. I see that my gnuplot requires to be closed and reopened whenever the `run.gnu` has an error, syntax or anything. (Thanks for your comments).

Comment: Typing `reset` (or `reset session` should be enough)